# How do you assert that a `Collection` of `Collection`s contains elements containing certain elements?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest, assertj

Let's say I have `String`s `"foo"`, `"bar"` and `baz`

and that I'm given a `Stream<String[]> candidates`.

I now want to `assertThat` all elements in `candidates` are tuples containing either `{"foo", "bar"}` (in any order) or `{"bar", "baz"}` (in any order).

How do I best do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `allMatch` or `allSatisfy` something like

```
assertThat(candidates).allMatch(candidate -> candidate.contains...)
```

or

```
assertThat(candidates).allSatisfy(
          candidate -> assertThat(candidate).satisfiesAnyOf(
                       c -> {      
                          c.contains("foo");
                          c.contains("bar");
                       },
                       c -> {      
                          c.contains("bar");
                          c.contains("baz");
                       })                                     
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to use `Stream#allMatch(Predicate)` to check the tuple for either the combination of `[foo, bar]` *or* `[bar, baz]` and the size of the tuple.

In the second step I have converted the inner array into a `Set<String>` which makes it easy to resolve cases like `[foo, foo]` as the duplicates would be removed and also we can use `Set.contains()` for a O(1) lookup to check either `[foo, bar]` *or* `[bar, baz]` is present in the stream of tuples:

```
class TupleTest {

@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void testTupleOfCandidates_True() {
    Stream<String[]> candidates = Stream.of(new String[]{"bar", "foo"}, new String[]{"bar", "baz"});
    assertTrue(isCandidateStreamValid(candidates));

    candidates = Stream.of(new String[]{"bar", "foo"}, new String[]{"bar", "baz"});
    assertTrue(isCandidateStreamValid(candidates));

}

@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void testTupleOfCandidates_False() {
    Stream<String[]> candidates = Stream.of(new String[]{"foo", "foo"}, new String[]{"bar", "baz"});
    assertFalse(isCandidateStreamValid(candidates));

    candidates = Stream.of(new String[]{"bar", "foo"}, new String[]{"bar", "baz"}, new String[]{"baz", "bar"});
    assertTrue(isCandidateStreamValid(candidates));
}

public boolean isCandidateStreamValid(Stream<String[]> candidates){
        return candidates.allMatch(arr -> {
            Set<String> data = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(arr));
            return data.size() == 2
                    &&
                    ((data.contains("foo") && data.contains("bar"))
                            ||
                            (data.contains("bar") && data.contains("baz")));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This would fail for, say, `{"foo", "foo"}`. (You also forgot to check that `arr` has size 2, btw.)

Comment: @User1291 Thanks for catching that, I fixed the code I posted earlier now it should work for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I'd create a function that can validate a tuple. This function will be called on each element in the stream. I would also create a second function that can check whether an array contains each element of another array. Something like this:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test(){
        Stream<String[]> stream = Stream.of(new String[]{"foo", "bar"}, new String[]{"bar", "baz"});
        stream.forEach(arr -> assertThat(validTuple(arr)).isTrue());

        //Order does not matter:
        stream = Stream.of(new String[]{"bar", "foo"}, new String[]{"baz", "bar"});
        stream.forEach(arr -> assertThat(validTuple(arr)).isTrue());

        //Invalid tuples
        stream = Stream.of(new String[]{"foo", "asdf"}, new String[]{"foo", "baz"});
        stream.forEach(arr -> assertThat(validTuple(arr)).isFalse());
    }

    private boolean validTuple(String[] array){
        if(array.length != 2) return false;
        return containsAll(array, "foo", "bar") || containsAll(array, "bar", "baz");
    }

    private boolean containsAll(String[] array, String... values){
        for (String value : values) {
            boolean containsValue = false;
            for (String s : array) {
                if(s.equals(value)){
                    containsValue = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!containsValue){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

You can now easily extract those methods to a dedicated class so you can re-use them in other tests if need be.

Comment: If we're going down that route, I suggest making your function a `Predicate` and using `stream.allMatch(validTuple)`.